# How to pass DateTimeExpression to set value on on-click in Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to pass a few values like(today, this weekend) to the goal using on-click. But unable to pass MyDateTimeExpression on Bixby.

```
  on-click{
           intent{
             goal:DateSearch
               value-set:CategoryName{CategoryName(clients)}
               value-set:MyDateTimeExpression{$expr(today)}
           }
         }
```

Anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: This question requires more information such as the definition of the Action you intend this on-click to trigger, the definition of MyDateTimeExpression, and the definitions of all the variables in this on-click's intent. I would recommend adding that information or reaching out to the support team via the IDE to get more personalized help.

Comment: I am giving the user a cell-card which has "Is there any Sports event for the next week". So sport is category and next week is DateTimeExpression.
So I am able to pass category but not time.

MyDateTimeExpression structure is :

  structure(MyDateTimeExpression){

    role-of(time.DateTimeExpression)
   features {
     transient
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `DateTimeExpression` to resolve words like "today", "this weekend", etc as part of a natural language utterance. You can train with Bixby to expect `DateTimeExpression` in your user's utterances as described in the documentation here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.datetime#training

In other words, you can't pass a string "today" like that in an intent as your example shows - that is not natural language coming from the user (instead, it's a string).